# Matrix Factorization in Recommender Systems: Uniqueness of SVD?

Tags: factor-analysis, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

I was studying the collaborative filtering approach about recommender system 
and I read about matrix factorization approach. In SVD version, 
I have not figured out how the non-uniqueness of the decomposition 
is not a problem for the recommendation process. 
By varying the decomposition 
 recommendations have to change.  Where theorically am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Non-uniqueness is not catastrophic, it does not imply that a solution is grossly biased or anything like that. (*to paraphrase a great*) Approximate answers to exact questions can be extremely useful. :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer,
then I try to rephrase the question. 
What guarantees  that two different approximations , are close to each other 
in the latent factors space ?

Comment: It is a comment not an answer. :) Welcome to the community by the way. I would suggest you edit our original post as well as its title to reflect your new take on the question. It will attract more attention (hopefully).

Comment: The singular vectors in SVD need not be unique, and it's ok.

Comment: We have no guarantee about the closeness in latent space. Two different decompositions can be arbitrarily far from one another (depending how you measure). What's important is that the ratings themselves stay the same. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are probably missing:
while the decomposition might not be unique, the reconstruction *is* unique. In other words, let's assume that $(U,V)$ and $(\tilde U,\tilde V)$ are two decompositions, which differ, e.g. by permuting the rows of both matrices (this corresponds to a permutation among the top $k$ of the singular values). While the decompositions are indeed different, the reconstruction matrices will be the same, i.e.

$$UV^T = \tilde U \tilde V^T.$$

since the recommended ratings are the elements of the reconstruction matrix, we see that **the recommendations remain the same**, even though the decompositions are different.

Does this make sense?